# Capturing git log output on Windows XP with Python

Tags: python, windows, git, windows-xp

This snippet of code works on most Unix I have access to (Linux, Solaris, AIX) as well as on Windows 7/ Server 2008 R2 and up that I've used to get the output of git log:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import platform

cmd = ["git", "--no-pager"]
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    cmd.append("--work-tree=/path/to/working/copy")
cmd.extend(["log", "--pretty=format:\"%cd %h\"", "--date=short", "--", "/path/to/working/copy/filename/to/check"])

proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
proc.wait()
f = proc.stdout
some_stuff = f.read()
f.close()
```

However, on Windows XP using msysgit I'm not getting any value to the some_stuff variable, which is weird since running the generated command works on the command line on Windows.

Any tips on what should I do here?

Comment: This could be an issue with the msysgit version on XP, have you tried with git from cygwin?

Comment: I tend to avoid Cygwin as much as I can as this requires too much retooling of the build system I am maintaining (a strange mix of MSBuild + GNU Make + batch files, and now with Python in the mix).

Comment: Worked around the issue by not specifying the `--work-tree` option on Windows, use git.cmd instead of git.exe on Windows, as well as making sure that the filename to check has its drive letter assignment in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, here's what I've found:

1. On Windows, msysgit recommends the use of the wrapper script `git.cmd` instead of directly specifying `git.exe`.
2. msysgit is especially sensitive of normalized path filenames, in particular the drive letter must be in uppercase, and that the case of the filenames must match how [GetLongPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would output.
3. Using forward slashes as well as backward slashes as path separators seems to still work.

By testing the above-mentioned, it seems that:

- There's no need really to specify the `--work-tree` option anymore
- "Normalizing" pathnames by passing it to `os.path.normpath()` will not work, as it will assume case-insensitivity and alter the drive letter to lowercase.
- Using the short pathname (the output of [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) will not work.